# Network does not learn much

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am training a very simple network on my dataset of RGB images, however it seems the network does not learn much, the val accuracy does not improve at all since the beginning, the training accuracy improves but very little. What am I doing wrong? It is a simple network, so I am not sure what goes so horribly wrong.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"

train_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/Bl/data/train'
eval_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/Bl/data/eval'
test_dir = '/home/d/Desktop/Bl/data/test'


# create a data generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,   #Scale the image between 0 and 1
                                    rotation_range=40,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  #We do not augment validation data. we only perform rescale

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  #We do not augment validation data. we only perform rescale

# load and iterate training dataset
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=16, shuffle='True', seed=42)
# load and iterate validation dataset
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(eval_dir, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=16, shuffle='True', seed=42)
# load and iterate test dataset
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, class_mode=None, batch_size=1, shuffle='False', seed=42)




model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  #Dropout for regularization
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))  #Sigmoid function at the end because we have just two classes

#Lets see our model
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-7, momentum=0.9), metrics=['acc']) 
#Adam(lr=0.000001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0), metrics=['acc']) 

#The training part
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size,
                              epochs=200,
                              validation_data=val_generator,
                              validation_steps=val_generator.n // val_generator.batch_size)

#Save the model
model.save_weights('/home/d/Desktop/Bl/model_weights.h5')
model.save('/home/d/Desktop/Bl/model_keras.h5')

#lets plot the train and val curve
#get the details form the history object
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

#Train and validation accuracy
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation accurarcy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
#Train and validation loss
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just by looking I can say a learning rate of 1e-7 is too small, you have to tune this parameter to make the loss go down consistently. You could also try the Adam optimizer with the default learning rate.

Comment: Thanks, I actually decreased it because more or less - maybe slightly worse the same thing happens with lr = 0.01 and in between

Comment: If the loss decreases little with that learning rate, then you should increase the learning rate, not decrease it. Did you try with Adam?

Comment: I have tried with Adam, so 0.001 started off (after my trials with 0.01) good but settled really quickly, then I tried 0.0001 and now it is back to the same behavior. First a few epochs, it seems like it is improving over epochs, then it begins to degrade - not change, curiously the change is small and it moves past the optimal point really soon - a couple of epochs only

Comment: I have also tried Adadelta with a scheduler (decreases lr when improvement is small) however it seems like I get something not much different than luck. So the network doesn't learn anything. I have 3 classes and val accuracy stays around 0.3333